# .bat file in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm trying to run a .bat file in my application. This .bat calls a JTAG application to load a firmware in microcontroller. However, I don't know why this fail in to execute the software. 
If I run the .bat outside of Visual Studio it works perfectly.

I have the GUI and a Button which I will click to execute the firmware loading

To generate the command files I used a software Uniflash. This software generates a folder with all necessary files to execute the JTAG access and load the firmware.

My code is below:

```
    private void Button_Relay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process MSP = new Process();
        MSP.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\\Projects\\Test_Fixture\\Test_Fixture_Visual_Studio\uniflash_windows_64";
        MSP.StartInfo.FileName = "dslite.bat ";
        MSP.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        MSP.WaitForExit();

    }
```

However when I executed this code the compilation is ok, but when I run this code appear this error:

[image]

Questions:

1. I will always generate specific bat files for each application and include the .bat folder inside the folder of VS C#, how I set up the directory path to check automatically in my software folder?
2. Why the VS can't find the files if the path is right?

[image]

3. After my .bat run I would like to read the status of the programming ( Success or fail ) How I do it?
   Success

[image]

Fail: 
[image]

Comment: Your mistake is on `MSP.StartInfo.FileName = "dslite.bat ";` If you **know** the folder where that batch file is stored then that string should **include** that path.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the space after `dslite.bat`?

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post .

Comment: try single backslashes instead of double in the folder name...you've used @ to make it a literal  string, so you shouldn't need to escape the slashes.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your first question. What do you mean with _how I set up the directory path to check automatically in my software folder_?

Comment: Dear mjwills and @ADyson, both are right about the problem. The remove the extra space and remove the double backslashes solved the problem my microcontroller is loading the firmware now. Amazing!

Answer (score 3):

Ad 2)

**About the error:**

That's because you may have specified the path wrong:

Instead of

```
MSP.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\\Projects\\Test_Fixture\\Test_Fixture_Visual_Studio\uniflash_windows_64";
```

either use `\\` everywhere (there is only one `\` between `Test_Fixture_Visual_Studio` and `uniflash_windows_64`) and skip the `@` **OR** use the `@` and just use one `\` instead of two. So replace your line with this one:

```
MSP.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\Projects\Test_Fixture\Test_Fixture_Visual_Studio\uniflash_windows_64";
```

Ad 3)

**About the result of your prcess:**

In my opinion it is easier to not call a batch file but to call the process itself directly. In this way you can retrieve the [`Process.ExitCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to retrieve the exit code of the executable (if it returns it's state via the exit code).
You can check this by calling the executable in the command shell and check the error level of the last execution by calling

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Usually `0` indicates success, everything else indicates a failure of some kind.